# How can I translate this Kotlin code into a better one using high order functions instead of a simple for

Tags: kotlin

I have this function that receives a barcode and looks for a product in a list that has the same barcode. The `split( ",")` is because there are some products that have more than one barcode written like this: `("barcode1,barcode2")`

Could someone help me get a better code using high order functions rather than this for loop?

```
fun Product.byBarcode(barcode: String?) : Product? {
    val productsList = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(Product::class.java).findAll().toMutableList()
    var foundProduct : Product? = null
    for (it in productsList){
        if ( it.barcode.split(",").contains(barcode)){
            foundProduct = it
            break
        }
    }
    return foundProduct

}
```

Comment: would be a bit easier to guide you in the correct direction if we could see the model for `Product`. Also, is there any particular reason why the param `barcode` is nullable? Also, isn't `Realm` a database of sorts? Are you really loading into memory your whole database, instead of just making a query to it?

Comment: You can use `first` to exit as soon ad first match is found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find`

```
foundProduct = productList.find{ it.barcode.split(',').contains(barcode) }
```

also I don't think split is really required, in that case

```
foundProduct = productList.find{ it.barcode.contains(barcode) }
```

Comment: You could simplify it even further with `{ barcode in it.barcode }`.

Comment: absolutely, we can do that as well